# How to send serial output from arduino to textbox with ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arduino

Would anyone happen to know how to receive a usb serial output from a device and send it to an html textbox using jQuery? I understand how to send a command using ajax and jQuery to a serial device, but I cannot figure out how to receive a message sent back from the device?

The following javascript is what I use for sending a message to the device, Arduino, from a button click:

```html
<!-- Arduino Serial Connection -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function() { 
 jQuery('#contact_form').on('click', '.button',function (e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); //prevents the default of submitting the form 
  jQuery.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
   url: '/test/SubmitFormWORefresh.php',
   data: "rcmd="+jQuery(this).val(),
      success: function() {
   alert('Enroll Your Finger Now');
          
   }
    });
    return false;
 });
 
});
 
</script>
```

And here is the SubmitFormWORefresh.php:

```html
<?php
$verz="1.0";
$comPort = "/dev/ttyACM0"; /*change to correct com port */
$PHP_SELF="index.php"; //This php file locate it from root

if (isset($_POST["rcmd"])) {
 $rcmd = $_POST["rcmd"];
 switch ($rcmd) {
      case "Stop":
  $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
  sleep(2);
    fwrite($fp, 1); /* this is the number that it will write */
    fclose($fp);
    break;
  
    case "Enroll":
  $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
  sleep(2);
    fwrite($fp, 3); /* this is the number that it will write */
    fclose($fp);
    break;
  default:
   die('Crap, something went wrong. The page just puked.');
 }/*end switch case*/
}/*end if statemen t*/
?>
```

The following code is from the index.html page that displays the button that javascript manipulates, and also the textbox that I want the output of the serial device to display to.

```html
<!----This is the button that I first send a message to the device -->
<div id="contact_form">
<form name="contact" action="">
   <fieldset>
     <input type="submit" name="rcmd" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Enroll" />
       </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<!----This is the textbox I need to send incoming data to-->
<input type="text" value="" id="table_0_fprint_id" data-key="fprint_id" data-input_type="text" class="editDialogInput  " />
```

After I click the button and send a message to the device, the device then sends a message over a serial connection back to the webpage. I need the javascript to input this message into the textbox. I know I will probably need use the GET function, but I cannot get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to handle the ajax response. In my example i called it **response** (argument to the anonymous function bind to success). Code is untested, but should work:

```html
<!-- Arduino Serial Connection -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function() { 
 jQuery('#contact_form').on('click', '.button',function (e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); //prevents the default of submitting the form 
  jQuery.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
   url: '/test/SubmitFormWORefresh.php',
   data: "rcmd="+jQuery(this).val(),
      success: function(response) {
       alert('Enroll Your Finger Now');
            $("input#table_0_fprint_id").val($(response).text());
   }
    });
    return false;
 });
 
});
 
</script>
```

You also have to make sure that `/test/SubmitFromWORefresh.php` script prints/echo'es a message to be placed in the `input` on response.

Comment: Will this determine the responding message if the message is sent about 1 minutes later?

Comment: This will determinate the responding message only if timeout isn't reached and the document is successfully loaded. As far as message isn't sent asynchronously this solution should work.

Comment: Ok, So I need to set my message equal to the variable "response"? How exactly would I do that in my SubmitFormWORefresh.php?

Comment: Everything what `SubmitFormWORefresh.php` returns (prints/echoes) will be set to the `response` variable.

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to get SubmitFormWORefresh.php to set the response variable. When I inspect the page this is what it gives me: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: response